# Save dropbox options in java

Tags: java, html

please help me to solve a problem. Here is my User POJO :

```
private int id;
private String email;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String password;
//property for dropdown field
// getters, setters
```

AND HTML:

```html
<td><select name="user_type">
  <option value="employee" selected>Employee</option>
  <option value="hirer">Hirer</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select></td>
```

What kind of property is better to use for saving option data in a POJO: enum, map, list ? which one is best practice?